# display an alert after a user clicks a submit,and comes back after processing in another php page

Tags: php

How can I display an alert or a message after a user clicks a submit button in a form?

I want the alert to show when the page has loaded after the submit button has been clicked.

When submit form is clicked its goes to another php page updated the db and and redirected to the form page itself. I am doing it in PHP. Is there anyway I can post data, check in the form page and display a hidden message?

```
header('Location: http://www.xxxxxx.co.uk/NottTest/editqr.php');
```

This is the redirect link after updating the DB, can I parse a message here?

This is the page where the db is updated ..

```
<body>

<p>
 <?php $sltdtpst= $_POST["qrtopic"]; ?>
 <?php $selctsm= $_POST["qrsubmenu"]; ?>
 <?php $selcttxt= $_POST["text12"]; ?>

 <?php
$link = mysql_connect('www.xxxxx.co.uk', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxx');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("web3fffasd", $link);

 $update = "UPDATE qr_table SET $selctsm = '$selcttxt' WHERE id_qr= $sltdtpst";

  mysql_query($update, $link);

mysql_close();


header('Location: http://www.xxxxxx.co.uk/NottTest/editqr.php');

?>


</p>

</body>
```

So after updating the database a hidden should be displayed here in the form page

```
<form name="updateqrnew" form action="edider1.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

    <div class="form_description">
            Update Contents for QR below
</div>                      
            <ul >

                    <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Quick refresher topics </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="qrtopic" name="qrtopic"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">Anxiety</option>

        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Submenu </label>
        <div>
        <select class="element select medium" id="qrsubmenu" name="qrsubmenu"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="start_of">Starting off</option>


        </select>
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_4" >
        <label class="description" for="element_4">Enter the article below</label>
        <div>
            <textarea id="text12" name="text12" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
        </div> 
        </li>

                    <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="431595" />

                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
        </li>
            </ul>
    </form>
```

Comment: Use your preferred header location link and just write to file. The script will first write to your `db` and redirect afterwards.

Comment: yes after redirecting ,when the form page is loaded again,i need to display a message on the page that db has been updated .Sorry if my question is confusing

Comment: What do you have as far as `code` goes?

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand that,you mean you want to see the code ?

Comment: You can set a delay on the redirect so you can print a message to the user before they are sent.

Comment: Do you have some PHP code we can look at?

Comment: yes i can set an alert before redirecting ,but it doesn't look good when updating via mobile devices

Comment: Some mobile devices' browsers may crash on popup alerts, look into that. May not be what you want. It happened to me. Would be better off with a simple `header` redirection.

Comment: You could probably insert a hidden div with a pre-configured message in an array, and using an `if` statement, `Javascript` and `CSS`. It's one way of doing it. Then again, after the user has submitted the form, why have them redirected to the form? Would probably better to have a `header location` going to a `your submission has been sent...` ect. something to that affect.

Comment: Am sure there are some `SQL` gurus out there, who may have another way of doing it.

Comment: @Fred This is not SQL related. Displaying a message to the user is the responsibility of the HTTP server.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder Ok. I know nothing about SQL, thought there may have been a way to do it inside an SQL directive.

Comment: In a way Rachel, you kind of answered your own question. The user will be redirected after it wrote to DB. Header is the final directive after any action taken before it. Have you tested your theory?

Comment: i was thinking about post a message also in php while redirecting ,and check the parsed code on the main page and display the hidden content ..i ma trying but i am not getting the code right

Comment: As previously stated Rachel, I would be weary of using any type of `popup` messages for `mobile` devices. If it crashes their browser, they may not want to go through the same process again, yet alone visit your site again. Take it from `experience`.

Comment: found the answer .. http://html.net/page.php?name=Joe

Comment: that link is a 404 for me,was it a temporary file?

Comment: Let me see if I understand this. The user clicks on a submit button, the action script processes it, then does a redirect to a new script, and you want to inform the user that their update worked, is that it? In this case, what you may want to look at is passing a result code from the action script to the redirect script. This can be done in a few ways, including using the query string, or using a cookie, or using sessions. The first is easy, but makes for a slightly more messy URL. The second is rather deprecated. The third is the more generally accepted way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I understand this

1. The user clicks on a submit button,
2. the action script processes it, then
3. does a redirect to a new script,

and you want to inform the user that their update worked, is that it?

In this case, what you may want to look at is passing a result code from the action script to the redirect script. Then the redirect script can lookup the result code passed in a emit the proper message to the user. (Does not have to be a pop-up, necessarily in this scenario.) Passing the result code can be done in a few ways, including using the query string, or using a cookie, or using sessions. The first is easy, but makes for a slightly more messy URL. The second is rather deprecated. The third is the more generally accepted way of doing this, but if this is the only place you'd need a session, is probably overkill for your application.

Using the query string, your redirect may look like this:

```
header('Location: http://www.xxxxxx.co.uk/NottTest/editqr.php?r=1');
```

where 1 can be a code for sucess, for example, or you could have other codes if there was an error you wanted to display, etc. If you need more information than just a code, you can pass that on the query string as well. Note that this does present some application security issues, so you have to ensure that your code will do the right thing if someone simply calls the redirect script directly with a query string that means something has happened in your application. That is why it's not the best way to do this.